# Styling Flash Object in css

Tags: flash, object, css

I have this object in page:

```
<object  id="iembedflash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="100%" height="500"> '+
'<param name="movie" value="<?php echo base_static_url(); ?>vendor/flash/camcanvas.swf" />'+
'<param name="quality" value="high" />'+
'<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />'+
'<embed  allowScriptAccess="always"  id="embedflash" src="<?php echo base_static_url(); ?>vendor/flash/camcanvas.swf" quality="high" width="100%" height="500" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" mayscript="true"  />'+
'</object>
```

I would like to style that by `css`. More specifically, I would like to put it under a `div`, then style the `div` with some `border-radius box shadow`.

How can i put it under main `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this code is being inserted using Javascript ...

Your formatting is not correct and it will give errors. I think you miscopied the code ... any way this should do what you need :

```
'<div class="object-container"><object  id="iembedflash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="100%" height="500"> '+
'<param name="movie" value="<?php echo base_static_url(); ?>vendor/flash/camcanvas.swf" />'+
'<param name="quality" value="high" />'+
'<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />'+
'<embed  allowScriptAccess="always"  id="embedflash" src="<?php echo base_static_url(); ?>vendor/flash/camcanvas.swf" quality="high" width="100%" height="500" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" mayscript="true"  />'+
'</object></div>'
```

Comment: i tryed but object element still not under the div object-container